# python tcpserver dont loop

Tags: python-2.7, tcp

Hello everyone and thank you for reviewing my question!

I'm new to python and following a tutorial from a book I bough where I'm stock at making a `tcpserver`

now it's written for python 2.x and I know I should do it for 3.x but I wanna start off by following hows it's explained in the book!

This is his code for a plain tcp server:

```
import socket
import threading

bind_ip = "0.0.0.0"
bind_port = 9999

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server.bind((bind_ip,bind_port))

server.listen(5)

print "[*] Listning on %s:%d" % (bind_ip,bind_port)

#this is our client-handling thread
def handle_client(client_socket):

    #print out what the client sends
    request = client_socket.recv(1024)

    print "[*] Recived: %s" % request

    #send back a packet
    client_socket.send("ACK!")

    client_socket.close()

    while True:

        client,addr = server.accept()

        print "[*] Accepted connection from: %s:%d" % (addr[0],addr[1])

    #spin up our client thread to handle incomming data

    client_handler = threading.Thread(target=handle_client,args=(client,))
    client_handler.start()
```

now this code fails when I run it from python 2.7.x giving me a invalid syntax %
so I changed some of the lines to support the .format as % issent supported anymore from what I've found googling around!

```
print "[*] Listning on {0}:{1}".format(bind_ip,bind_port)
print "[*] Recived: {0}".format(request)
print "[*] Accepted connection from: {0}:{1}".format(addr[0],addr[1])
```

when i run it now it spits out: `[*] Listning on 0.0.0.0:9999`
great right? NO because for some reason I can't figure out the while loop don't execute so it breaks out of the .py after a second so I can't test `the tcp server script` with my `tcp client script`

Can someone tell me what I'm going wrong?

Comment: Show the complete error message with traceback.  Also, `%` formatting is still supported even though `format` is the new way to do it.

Comment: sorry to waste your time the probblem was my line spacing i usally progam in php that ain't space case sensitive causs its inclosed in brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should start the thread out side of the function. If you note the identation, the `while` loop is part of `handle_client` and hence you see the script exit as soon as printing "Listning on....."

```
def handle_client(client_socket):
   #Function defnition
while True:

        client,addr = server.accept()

        print "[*] Accepted connection from: %s:%d" % (addr[0],addr[1])
        client_handler = threading.Thread(target=handle_client,args=(client,))
        client_handler.start()
```